# If "This question was voluntarily removed by its author," what is the purpose of the text that follows?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, status-completed

[image: A screenshot of the 404 page on Christianity.SE, with a bit of specific explanatory text followed by general-purpose "how to look for something that no longer exists" suggestions]

---

The additional text seems superfluous.  I daresay it could be confusing to a new user, who might actually be compelled to search or browse for the missing page.

Comment: Changed to [feature-request], so The Team will see it.  See below for potential solution.

Answer (score 20):

The page could confuse a new user, who is first told the question was deleted by the user, and  then gets the suggestion to try searching for it.

Instead of saying, "Try searching for it," the page could say, "Try searching for similar questions." This would be compatible with the list of questions that is reported right after that phrase, and which seems a list of questions the system thinks are correlated with the question the user is trying to see.

Comment: Actually, that sounds like a reasonable, easy to implement solution.

Comment: How did I manage to write "trey searching"? Sigh!

Comment: I implemented "searching for similar questions" -- great idea!